# C# Склеить 2 Image

Tags: c#, графика

Есть 2 Image:
Первое (1280x720):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И другое (530x352):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно получить в 1280x720:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Те добавить на первое второе которое < первого на X - 0, Y - 0

Comment: Ага, вы что-нибудь пробовали уже делать?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Bitmap пустой и Graphics.FromImage(bitmap) и graphics.DrawImage...

Comment: Вы хотя бы пробовали искать? Вот небольшой [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12870849/6808809) одной из реализации. Если пробовали, редактируйте вопрос, добавляйте код, пишите что конкретно не получается!